# regular expression for searching from the last

Tags: regex

I have a text like this:

`>>> Dinner: <a class="Link" href="/" >rice</a> <<<`

and the regular expression I have is

`(>.*?<\/a)`

This is giving me the text `>>> Dinner: <a class="Link" href="/" >rice</a` but I just want `rice`

Any help??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
(?<=>)[^<>]*(?=<\/a)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD0sJ3/8

You need to use `lookaheads` to make sure you capture only `rice` and not other symbols.

Comment: don't lie, i'm the first who posted the lookaround solution.

Comment: you guys are funny :)

Comment: you guys started downvoting each other and started downvoting question also..even at 22.6k and 65.3k score ??

Comment: @javanoob are you kidding, why we going to downvote your question?

Comment: And i wondered why the answer which was posted first got 3 downvotes and the second got 2 downvotes? lol.

Comment: @AvinashRaj probably the one saw urs first...put a downvote to question,ur answer got bored left :P

Comment: I did upvote for both of yours..thats why it went -3 , -2 to -2 and -1

Comment: @javanoob downvotes to your question is mainly because of parsing html files with regex.

Comment: @AvinashRaj and what about those encouraging it?

Comment: @AmitJoki i think op know the consequences of parsing html files with regex.

Answer (score -1):

Use a negated characterclass along with capturing group.

```
>([^<>]*)<\/a
```

Grab the string you want from group index 1.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oN6rL2/2)

**OR**

```
(?<=>)[^<>]*(?=<\/a)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oN6rL2/3)